# I can’t get rid of pink objects

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

I’m new to Nlender.

I think I’ve deleted my texture files by accident.
I’ve watched several videos on how to try to sort this but nothing is working.
I’ve tried uninstalling but I have a Mac and it’s not uninstalling everything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I open up shading or texture paint, the object is pink. Which means missing texture files. I’ve tried to find them and report them. Nothing changes. My object remains pink.

Comment: You said you think you've probably deleted the files by accident. If they are deleted, there's no way Blender will find them and then it's normal that everything stays pink. The "Find Missing Files" function is to tell Blender where files are if you moved them from the original position. If they are completely gone this won't help - Blender is no recovery tool for deleted files.

Comment: Oh no, so I need to completely uninstall it from the MacBook then?   Because when I install it, it isn’t uninstalling it completely.  maybe if I restore my MacBook. I don’t know

Comment: Thank you. So much, I thought this was the problem. I can’t believe I did this.

Comment: ...actually I don't understand what deleted texture files have to do with installing/uninstalling Blender.

Comment: How can I get the files again? 
I can’t remember how I done it lol I am new to blender.

Comment: When you are talking about deleted files, you mean files that you removed from your computer? 1. look in the recycle bin of your computer, in Windows you can "undelete" them, I don't know if it's the same for Mac and 2. if this is about deleted files, this is not a Blender-specific problem.

Comment: I’ve Been all through my recycle bin. I thought it was an image when I deleted it. . It’s ok, I’m going to watch some lessons in learning blender, maybe il find the solution along the way. Thank you